# Change the name of a bookmark

Tags: beamer, hyperref, bookmarks

I have long titles for sections in a TeX-Beamer presentation. By default, `hyperref` uses the name of the section for the `pdfbookmark`. This means the bookmark is too long. I would like to use a shorter name in the bookmark. Does somebody know to to do that? Let's say I have

```
\section{Algorithm to determine firms' entry and exit into the market}
```

By default the bookmark is the same name of the section, so it will also be long. I would like to have a shorter bookmark, like "Entry and Exit". I don't how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean: `\section[Entry and Exit]{Algorithm to determine firms' entry and exit into the market}`?

Answer (score 9):

`\texorpdfstring` can be used, the first argument is the usual section text, the second argument the text for the bookmark:

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{Long version}{Short version}}
```

If the short version should also be used for the table of contents, the optional argument of `\section` can be used:

```
\section[Short version]{Long version}
```